# How can you solve for a b and c

Tags: systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system

I have this system of equations that I want to solve: $$\begin{cases}
a+b = 204 \\ a+b\cdot e^{-105c} = 192.6 \\ a+b\cdot e^{-180c} = 177.6\end{cases}$$

Is there a mathematical way to solve it knowing that the constant will keep changing? I am looking for a way that I can program it to do the mathematical work for me.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Could you please clarify your question showing if $b$ is multiplied by $exp(...)$ or the whole $a+b$ (try to use parentheses), also this site supports MathJax so please try to use it and correct spelling mistakes. I would suggest an edit but  I don't know exactly what you want.

Comment: Do what @Ethan Bolker suggested : you will get a much simpler equation to solve that the one given in another answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: With $$b=204-a$$ we get
$$a+(204-a)e^{-105c}=\frac{1926}{10}$$
$$a+(204-a)e^{-180c}=\frac{1776}{10}$$
From the first equation above we get
$$a=\frac{3 \left(321 e^{105 c}-340\right)}{5
   \left(e^{105 c}-1\right)}$$
Substituting this in the second equation above we get
$$\frac{3 \left(321 e^{105 c}-340\right)}{5 \left(e^{105
   c}-1\right)}+e^{-180 c} \left(204-\frac{3 \left(321
   e^{105 c}-340\right)}{5 \left(e^{105
   c}-1\right)}\right)=\frac{888}{5}$$
This must be solved for $c$
$$c\approx -0.006906341040$$

Answer (score 0):

If you subtract the second equation from the first you get
$$
b(1 - e^{-105c}) = 204 - 192.6.
$$
If you do the same for the third and first you get an equation with the same shape.

Divide one of those equations by the other and you have a single equation involving just $c$.

You will have to solve that one numerically.

Answer (score 0):

If you do what @Ethan Bolker suggested, using whole numbers, you should end with
$$\frac{57 e^{105 c}}{5 \left(e^{105 c}-1\right)}=\frac{132 e^{180 c}}{5 \left(e^{180
   c}-1\right)} $$ Reduce to same denominator and simplify to get
$$3 e^{105 c} \left(44 e^{75 c}-25 e^{180 c}-19\right)=0$$
So, you look for the zero of function
$$f(c)=44 e^{75 c}-25 e^{180 c}-19$$ that you will need to solve using, say, Newton method.

Looking at the equation, the solution has to be quite small. Expand $f(c)$ as a Taylor series to get
$$f(c)=1200 c+281250 c^2+O\left(c^3\right)$$ Then, an estimate of the solution is
$$c_0=-\frac{8}{1875}$$ Now, Newton iterates would be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & c_n \\
 0 & -0.004266666667 \\
 1 & -0.008648470966 \\
 2 & -0.007013654476 \\
 3 & -0.006907055886 \\
 4 & -0.006906341073 \\
 5 & -0.006906341040
\end{array}
\right)$$